# How to replace all symbols except several?

Tags: replacement

I'm doing some heavy symbolic calculations and for preliminary simple tests I need to replace all coefficients except chosen with 1, e.g.:

```
eq = a b c d e f g ...
Replace[eq, Except[a | b] -> 1]
```

> a b ...

Surely that's not working, just illustration. How can I do this?

A little remark: `eq/.(c|d|e|f|g|...)->1` will give what I want, but the point is there could be too many coefficients with different names, so it's much easier to write down only the those I want to keep.

Comment: `Replace[x^y + a/h - z + k, Except[a | x, _Symbol] -> 1, {0, Infinity}]` ?  `Heads -> False` is the default for `Replace`.

Comment: Oh... thanks a lot. I didn't think about Symbol...

Comment: But I'm not very happy about this solution.  For example, `Pi` is a symbol too and you probably wouldn't want to replace it ...  I'd rather make a list of all relevant symbols first and work with that.  Just to make sure nothing is included that shouldn't be ...

Comment: In this example this works .. `eq /. Cases[ Variables[eq] , v : Except[a | d] :> v -> 1 ]`

Comment: as an alternative possibility: `Times @@ ToExpression /@ (StringReplace[Map[ToString, List @@ eq], 
    Except[Characters["ab"]] -> "1"])  `. Try.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch it won't go for heavier expression as previously mentioned `a^b c d..` or like  `c d e f g astroboy1`. I guess complete symbolic parser is not the simplest solution.

Comment: @funnypony, why don't you then place the expression you have in mind?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I believe it's not necessary as the problem is clear. Moreover, I mentioned that equations are quite heavy - they occupy about several pages in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

A useful function is `Variables[]`, which returns a list of variables in `eq`.

```
eq = a b c d e f g π;

eq /. (Rule[# , 1] & /@ Complement[Variables[eq], {a, b}])

(* a b π *)
```

Comment: Though `Variables[x^a]` is `{x^a}`, not `{x,a}`.

Comment: Already to be found somewhere on the site as a substitute for `Variables`:  DeleteDuplicates[Cases[eq, _Symbol, -1]]

Answer (score 3):

I dare to post as an answer a very slightly enchanced **Szabolcs'** comment, which doesn't touch `Pi` or `E` and deprived of problems with `Variables`:

```
eq = a^(b + b1) c d e Pi E^Pi;
Replace[eq, Except[a | b | _?NumericQ, x_Symbol] -> 1, All]
```

> a^(1 + b) E^Pi Pi

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement this is as follows:

Create a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html?q=List) of [`Rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html?q=Rule) to [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll) [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html?q=Variables) with 1:

```
rules1 = # -> 1 & /@ Variables[eq]
    (* {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 1, h -> 1, i -> 1, j -> 1, k -> 1, l -> 1, m -> 1, n -> 1, o -> 1, p -> 1, q -> 1, r -> 1, s -> 1, t -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1} *)
```

Join to the front of this list of rules a new list with the variables you don't want replaced with 1:

```
rules2 = Join[{a -> a, b -> b}, # -> 1 & /@ Variables[eq]]
    (* {a -> a, b -> b, a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 1, h -> 1, i -> 1, j -> 1,  k -> 1, l -> 1, m -> 1, n -> 1, o -> 1, p -> 1, q -> 1, r -> 1, s -> 1, t -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1} *)
```

Then use ReplaceAll with the new, second list of rules:

```
eq /. rules2
    (* a b *)
```

You can combine these steps in a single expression, which avoids the creation of unnecessary symbols ("rules1" and "rules2" here):

```
eq /. Join[{a -> a, b -> b}, # -> 1 & /@ Variables[eq]]
    (* a b *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following, more robust code works both for the expression `eq` of the OP as well as for more complicated expressions, such as:

```
eq2 = a^(b + b1) c d e Pi E^Pi
```

As one-line code, one can use the following:

```
eq2 /. Join[{a -> a, b -> b}, # -> 1 & /@ Intersection@Flatten[Cases[#, _?AtomQ, {0, Infinity}] & /@ Variables[eq2]]]
    (* a^(1 + b) E^π π *)
```

This is built up as follows. First, [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) is used, but only on [`Atoms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html) in the expression. Nested lists are then [`Flattened`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) and duplicates are removed with [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.htmlhttp://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html).

```
varslist = Intersection@Flatten[Cases[#, _?AtomQ, {0, Infinity}] & /@ Variables[eq2]]
    (* {a, b, b1, c, d, e} *)
```

Second, a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of [`Rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) is created to replace all variables in `varslist` with 1. Then [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) to the front of this list of rules a new list with the variables you don't want replaced with 1. Finally, [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) is used on the expression `eq2`:

```
eq2 /. Join[{a -> a, b -> b}, # -> 1 & /@ varslist]
    (* a^(1 + b) E^π π *)
```