# How do I get a list of all the variable present in an algebraic expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an algebraic expression

```
(l[d,1]/(-l[d,1]+m[dd,1] p[dd]+m[du,1] p[du])+l[d,2]/(-l[d,2]+m[dd,2] p[dd]+m[ud,2] p[ud])+l[u,1]/(-l[u,1]+m[uu,1] p[uu])+l[u,2]/(-l[u,2]+m[uu,2] p[uu]))/(l[d,1]+l[d,2]+l[u,1]+l[u,2])
```

and I want to get a list of all the variables that are present in it excluding the mathematical operators , e.g.,
`{l[d,1], m[dd,1], p[dd], ...}`.
That is, replace all the heads that are `Plus`, `Power` or `Times` by the head `List`, `Flatten` the resulting list and remove the duplicates. How do I do that?

Comment: Short answer，Ma thematic does not have such a function. Unlike Maple, you can use 'indets'. But sometimes, you can try Variables[] with Level[] to get an answer in Mathematica. I have asked the same thing before, and there is no unified answer that can give you a satisfied answer if you are only looking for "variables", not in Mathematica.

Comment: also see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61131/get-all-variables-in-an-expression-with-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = (l[d, 1]/(-l[d, 1] + m[dd, 1] p[dd] + m[du, 1] p[du]) + l[d, 2]/(-l[d, 2] + m[dd, 2] p[dd] + m[ud, 2] p[ud]) + l[u, 1]/(-l[u, 1] + m[uu, 1] p[uu]) + l[u, 2]/(-l[u, 2] + m[uu, 2] p[uu]))/(l[d, 1] + l[d, 2] + l[u, 1] + l[u, 2])

vars = Variables[f]
```

Output

```
{l[d, 1], l[d, 2], l[u, 1], l[u, 2], m[dd, 1], p[dd], m[du, 1], p[du],  m[dd, 2], m[ud, 2], p[ud], m[uu, 1], p[uu], m[uu, 2]}
```

Honestly speaking, I have seen before a similar answer using the `Variable` here, but can't find it. If someone find it please post it on comment. I would be glad to add the reference.

Comment: Thanks ! `Variables` was the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr=(l[d, 1]/(-l[d, 1] + m[dd, 1] p[dd] + m[du, 1] p[du]) + l[d, 2]/(-l[d, 2] + m[dd, 2] p[dd] + m[ud, 2] p[ud]) + l[u, 1]/(-l[u, 1] + m[uu, 1] p[uu]) + l[u, 2]/(-l[u, 2] + m[uu, 2] p[uu]))/(l[d, 1] + l[d, 2] + l[u, 1] + l[u, 2])

Variables[Level[expr, 2]]
```

Again, there is no such single function in Mathematica, but you can try combinations of functions like 'Variables' and 'Level'.
If you have [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=indets), `indets` is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67603/how-to-replace-all-symbols-except-several/67731#67731):

```
varslist = Select[Intersection@
  Flatten[Cases[#, _?AtomQ, {0, Infinity}] & /@ Variables[orig]],
  Not@NumberQ[#] &]
```

> {d, dd, du, u, ud, uu}

where `orig` is your original expression.